# add a rounded border to content sticked to window (html & css)

Tags: html, css

I want to design a site, where the corners of the page are rounded (black circle on all the corners of the window).

To do so I've setted the body color to black, and I've added a rouded corner to the content div, a part form its background.

```
<body style="backgound: black">
  <div class="content" style="background: blue; border-radius: 8px;">
   ....
  </div>
</body>
```

After that I've tried:

**Not working solution 1**

```
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
```

Not working when content height is larger than window, because the content background hiddes when scrolled.

**Not working solution 2**

```
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
```

Not working when content height is larger than window; no scroll bar displayed.

**Not working solution 3**

Nothing at all.

Not working when content height smaller than window; the bottom part is left black.

**Ugly working solution 1**

Add 4 images with the border, with fixed position

Any one know a clean solution to the problem? css3 is accepted.

THanks

Comment: Body black bg is mandatory??

Comment: No, but its how I try to do the black background on the blue rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help:

```
.content
{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background blue;
   border-radius: 8px;
}
```

**EDIT** this solution will work:

```
.content
{
   float:left;
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
   background: blue;
   border-radius: 8px;
}
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDBJa/1/)

another example using css3 `calc()` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VDBJa/4/)

Comment: This is the proposed "Not working solution 1", that does not work  when content height is larger than window, as descrived in the post

Comment: nice try! but this does not work either. The bottom rounded border is not displayed untill you scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Take a look at last example. It's what you wanted, but i would use custom `scrollbar` for it.

Comment: Wow! I did not know about calc. However it does not work in any mobile browsers according to: http://caniuse.com/calc And I need the html to be used in a mobile app. +1, but waiting if any solution that actually solves my problem.

Comment: For mobile versions use javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `height:100%`

```
body, html{height:100%}
.content{height:100%}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X4mbL/1/)**

Comment: This is the proposed "Not working solution 1", that does not work  when content height is larger than window, as descrived in the post

Answer (score 0):

Use two nested fixed divs for header, and the same for footer.

This will work with every kind of content, on every browser:

Running Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5kgN3/

HTML

```
<div id="headerOuter"><div id="headerInner"></div></div>
<div class="content">
    <br />test
    <br />test
    <!-- More tests here -->
    <br />test
    <br />test
</div>
<div id="footerOuter"><div id="footerInner"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {    
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#headerOuter{
    background-color: black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

#headerInner{
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;    
}

#footerOuter{    
    background-color: black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

#footerInner{
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I used 20px of border-radius, when adjusting that to your 8px, remember to adjust paddings and heights.

Comment: Not working either. You can see that in the corners, the text is beeing hidden under the footer and header Inners, not when they reach the corner.

Comment: Theoretically, the question is good. I'm still trying. Practically, with 8px rounded borders, the problem is a non-problem: I hope you will have at least 8px of padding (on every side, laterals too), or the design will really suck...

Comment: This is for mobile device app. No padding used, and nice design.